# Fourier transform is continuous using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, epsilon-delta

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is given by
$$\hat{f}(\xi):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi} f(x) dx.$$
The dominated convergence theorem confirms that the Fourier transform is a continuous function. Indeed, if the sequence $\xi_n\rightarrow \xi_0$ then
$\hat{f}(\xi_n)\rightarrow\hat{f}(\xi_0)$ since, for every $n\geq 1$, $|e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi_n} f(x)|\leq |f(x)|\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I want to prove that $\hat{f}$ is continuous using the $\epsilon$ -$\delta$ definition.

My attempt:

Fix $\xi_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\epsilon>0$. We need to prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|\xi-\xi_0|<\delta \implies |\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi_0)|<\epsilon.$$

We have
$$\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi_0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}-e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi_0}) f(x) dx.$$
Define
$$g(t):=e^{-2\pi i x\cdot ((1-t)\xi+t\xi_0)}.$$
Then $g$ is a smooth function. By the mean-value theorem
$$e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}-e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi_0}=g(1)-g(0)= g^{\prime}(s)=
2\pi i e^{-2\pi i x\cdot ((1-s)\xi+s\xi_0)}x\cdot (\xi-\xi_0)$$
for some $s\in (0,1)$.

Therefore
$$\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi_0)=2\pi i (\xi-\xi_0)\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-2\pi i x\cdot ((1-s)\xi+s\xi_0)}x f(x) dx.$$

Now, if $f$ has compact support, or decay faster than $1/|x|$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$ we are done since, in that case,

$$|\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi_0)|\leq C |\xi-\xi_0|$$

with $C=2\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |x| |f(x)| dx$.

If $f$ is just an $L^1$ function we must use the cancellation due to the oscillatory exponential factor (may be using Riemann-Lebesgue lemma).

Comment: For general $f\in L^1$, you can approximate $f$ by $C_c^\infty$ functions. Note that $\|\hat g\|_{L^\infty}\leq \|g\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: Use $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=2|\sin((a-b)/2)|$ and $|\sin u|\le\min(|u|,1)$ as alternative to the mean value argument. Check if the assumptions for the mean-value theorem are really satisfied without putting the claim into the assumptions.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann The estimates you give for the sine function are correct, but they don't seem to help with the proof. I don't understand the second line "Check...". The mean value theorem is applicable here because $t\mapsto e^{-2\pi i (1-t)\xi+t\xi_0}$ is smooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some properties of $L^{1}$ functions (which may themselves involve DCT).

You cannot prove this directly for an arbitrary $L^{1}$ function without using some such property.

You can show that given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $M$ such that $\int_{\{x: |x|>M\}} |f| <\epsilon$. Note that $\int_{|x|>M} |e^{-2\pi ix.\xi}-e^{-2\pi ix.\xi_o}||f(x)|dx <2\epsilon$. For the integral over $\{x: |x| \leq M\}$ you can use your argument.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto e^{-2\pi ix.\xi}$ is not an $L^1$ function.  Could you please show how $\int_{|x|>M} |e^{-2\pi ix.\xi}-e^{-2\pi ix.\xi_o}|dx <2\epsilon$  ? I suspect $|f(x)|$ is missing, right?

Comment: @Medo Yes. Thanks for editing.